# Pandas and CSV files: How to get unique, sliced column values?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a file which contains a POSTCODE column. A UK postcode typically looks like `SW1A 0AA` with that space in the middle.

I know I can use `drop_duplicates()` to get unique values but I want that to apply to only the *first* part of the postcode (i.e., the `SW1A` part). I can probably manage it but converting it to a list then doing some string slicing e.g., `.split(' ')[0]`, then getting the unique values but that seems overly cumbersome. So I wonder if there's a nicer way of doing this?

What I have so far is:

```
df['POSTCODE'].drop_duplicates().to_list()
```

which as I already mentioned drops duplicates of the whole postcode, not the first part.

EDIT: just to make it easier to visualise, here's a sample of the csv file:

```
POSTCODE  |  PRICE_BAND

SW1A 0AB              9
SW1A 0AC              8
SW1A 0AD              7
SW1A 0AE              7
```

so what I'd like to be able to do eventually is group all those above postcodes into just `SW1A` and be able to get the average of `7.75` for the `PRICE_BAND` for SW1A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the first word by [`.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex `(\w+)` and get the unique values by [`.unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) before conversion to list, as follows:

```
df['POSTCODE'].str.extract(r'(\w+)', expand=False).unique().tolist()
```

### Demo

```
data = {'POSTCODE': ['SW1A 0AA', 'SW1A 0AB', 'SW2A 0AB', 'SW2A 0AC', 'SW3A 0AA']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   POSTCODE
0  SW1A 0AA
1  SW1A 0AB
2  SW2A 0AB
3  SW2A 0AC
4  SW3A 0AA

df['POSTCODE'].str.extract(r'(\w+)', expand=False).unique().tolist()

['SW1A', 'SW2A', 'SW3A']
```

### Edit

To group all the postcodes into just SW1A and be able to get the average of 7.75 for the PRICE_BAND for SW1A, you can do:

Group by the first word extracted by using `.groupby()` with the group as the extracted first word with [`.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), then use [`GroupBy.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) to get the average within the group.

```
df.groupby(df['POSTCODE'].str.extract(r'(\w+)', expand=False)).mean().reset_index()
```

Input:

```
   POSTCODE  PRICE_BAND
0  SW1A 0AB           9
1  SW1A 0AC           8
2  SW1A 0AD           7
3  SW1A 0AE           7
```

Output:

```
  POSTCODE  PRICE_BAND
0     SW1A        7.75
```

### Edit2

If you want to go about referencing one specific column grouped by postcode e.g., calculate the mean for PRICE_BAND, but the median for a FLOOD_RISK column, you can use:

```
df.groupby(df['POSTCODE'].str.extract(r'(\w+)', expand=False)).agg({'PRICE_BAND': 'mean', 'FLOOD_RISK': 'median'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: Amazing! That worked like a charm. And how would I go about referencing one specific column grouped by postcode e.g., calculate the mean for PRICE_BAND, but the median for a FLOOD_RISK column?

Comment: Thanks very much - one last question before I leave you alone I promise! I've tried using ```size()``` and ```count()``` to get the number of PRICE_BAND values used to calculate the mean but I don't think I'm doing it right. So in that 1st edit of yours, I'd want to retrieve the count of PRICE_BAND values which is 4. Sorry for so many questions - I feel like I'm just getting you to do all my work for me...! I'm just a bit awful at using pandas as a beginner.

Comment: @mlan  So what exactly is the question ?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. How would I get the number of values that were used to calculate the PRICE_BAND mean per POSTCODE?

Comment: @mlan  If like the first edit, you can replace `.mean()` with `.count()`  Similarly, for the 2nd edit, you can replace the 'mean' with 'count' for PRICE_BAND